# Get all the strings in strings.xml

Tags: java, android, string, localization, iteration

In my app, for localization I have a `values-ar` folder for arabic strings. The problem is that the arabic alphabet appears unconnected in phones which do not have Arabic language installed. I'm using the [ArabicReshape class](https://github.com/AZIZHUSS/Arabic-Reshaper/blob/master/src/com/AzizHuss/ArabicRehaper/ArabicReshape.java) to join the arabic alphabets but since I have too many strings, I cannot manually keep applying the reshaper class one by one.

I would like to know if I can get **all** the strings from the `strings.xml` file and apply the class to the strings at one go by looping through them. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible unfortunately...

Comment: @Orabîg Sorry to disappoint you, but this is possible, see answer ;-)

Comment: Good point :) Didn't think of using reflection. Gratz...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to iterate thrtough ALL strings instead of calling the class when you need one specific string.

But as you asked...

I guess this might help you ;-)

```
Field[] fields = R.string.class.getFields();
    for(final Field field : fields) {
       String name = field.getName(); //name of string
       try{
           int id = field.getInt(R.string.class); //id of string
       }catch (Exception ex) {
           //do smth
       }
    }
```

Comment: I am asking because of curiosity. What is the use of `final` in `for` loop?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand. How do I call the class when I need one specific string?

Comment: I cannot try because I have no time and no Arabic knowledge, but ArabicReshape.reshape(String Str) should do the trick

Comment: Oh okay. I am already doing that. But there are way too many strings to apply the class manually for each string.

Comment: Wow. It works. But I got strings.xml strings with some other extra strings. Because the R class hads `public static final class string {}` inner class.Iin this class had some extra static final variables like `public static final int abc_action_bar_home_description=0x7f060000;` including strings.xml strings. Now how can I get strings.xml strings only

Answer (score 1):

What you would have to do is set your **LOCALE** to *AR* so that the resource manager will let you pull out string from values-ar/strings.xml, then get a list of [Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html)s using reflection [R.string.class.getFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29).  Then iterate through your strings and do your reshaping.

Try something like the following code snippet :

```
Resources resources = getResources();
int resourceId = 0;
String resourceString;
Field[] stringFields = R.string.class.getFields();
for(Field stringField : stringFields) {

    try {
        resourceId = stringField.getInt(R.string.class);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    }

    resourceString = resources.getString(resourceId);
    if(resourceString != null && resourceString.length() > 0) {
        // do your reshaping on the resoureString
    }
}
```